# Sending object stream as a response in Koa

Tags: node.js, stream, koa, nodejs-stream, cassandra-driver

I want to stream a DB query result directly to the client as an array of objects. [DB driver returns a Readable Streams2 stream in object mode, emitting `Row` instances](https://github.com/datastax/nodejs-driver#row-streaming-and-pipes). Koa only accepts string mode streams. What is the best way to do the conversion between the two types in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Pipe the stream from the DB to a Transform stream and convert the object to string there

```
ctx.body = dbResultStream.pipe(
    new Transform({
      objectMode: true,
      transform(chunk, encoding, callback) {
        callback(null, JSON.stringify(chunk));
      }
    })
  );
```